# IIf (day(now().... in rdlc expression shows error

Tags: expression, rdlc

`IIf (day(now()`.... in rdlc expression shows error.

I am using visual studio 2014..

here is my code:

```
=iff( day(now()) >= 1 AND day(now()) <=7, MonthName(month(dateadd("m",-1, Fields!MONTH.Value)),false), MonthName(month(Fields!MONTH.Value),false)))
```

here is the problem:

> Error 1   The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘MONTH.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30451] 'iff'
>   is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection
>   level.    C:\Users\Anil\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\SyllRepo\SyllRepo\Report2.rdlc  SyllRepo

Answer (score 2):

Should be `iif` instead of `iff`:

```
=iif( day(now()) >= 1 AND day(now()) <=7, MonthName(month(dateadd("m",-1, Fields!MONTH.Value)),false), MonthName(month(Fields!MONTH.Value),false)))
```

Comment: oops thanks. but still shows error. then changed "now()" to  "now" : iif( day(now) >= 1.....  it worked... Thank you so much...

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error I have added the following Namespace to my file

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
```